# Selenium C #- How do I bring current Driver to front /focus?

Tags: c#, selenium, automation

I've searched into another topics and question but I couln't find something related to C#

I've tried:

```
ChromeDriver chrome = new ChromeDriver(options);

getDriver().switchTo().window(chrome.Title);
```

But I get the error:

> "No such windows"

Any ideas. Thank you !

Comment: See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/16428/21350 - the second answer

Comment: @JeremyThompson This have worked Perfectly!!!! Thank youu Jeremy!!